# exception in iText pdf creation

Tags: exception, itext, java-5

I Am trying to generate a table using iText (for testing only, thats why i am not using any servlet and class).I have used [this](http://www.geek-tutorials.com/java/itext/servlet_jsp_output_pdf.php) tutorial as my reference.
The code doesnt shows any errors but am getting an exception in run time

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

I use itext version 5.3.2,java 5. my code is given below.

**MY CODE**

```
<%@page import="java.io.DataOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException"%>
<%@page import="java.io.DataOutput"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter"%>
<%@page import="java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Document"%>       
<%

response.setContentType("application/pdf");
Document document = new Document();
try{
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, buffer);
document.open();


PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.addCell("1");
table.addCell("2");
table.addCell("3");
table.addCell("4");
table.addCell("5");
table.addCell("6");


document.add(table);
document.close();

DataOutput dataOutput = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
{
dataOutput.writeByte(bytes[i]);
}

}catch(DocumentException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}

%>
```

**EXCEPTION**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:387)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:606)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:195)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:124)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:117)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:191)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:115)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
    org.apache.jsp.generatepdf_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.generatepdf_jsp:99)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the top of the page use the this

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

we should also add `flush`/`close` for you dataOutput.

```
dataOutput.flush();
dataOutput.close();
return;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But,
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %> shows an error.

dataOutput.close();
return;
stream close works fine, And I am getting the out put, But still the consolve shows exception like

java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Comment: if so  in the jsp-config section your web.xml <jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>

Comment: i put in in web.xml it shows an error with the tag </trim-directive-whitespaces>. can you tell me the problem with the code? so i can google it for alternative solutions

Comment: @thebuffer here is the link that show your proper solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519642/jsp-trimspaces-directive-not-working

Comment: OK i get it. unfortunately i am using tomcat 5. so i think this tag is not supported

Comment: :-) i think you should upgrade you tomcat version.